# Swapping std::functions with user-implemented swaps

Tags: c++, swap, functor

I have created a functor which defines its own swap function. For simplicity assume that the functor's operator signature is int (int). If I initialize TWO std::function with that functor, say std_func1 and std_func2, will swapping them call the user-implemented swap function of the functor or not? Thanks in advance.

Here is what I have tried:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <boost/function.hpp>

using namespace std;

class myclass {

public:
  myclass(int n):data_(n,0){}

  void swap(myclass& rhs) {
    using std::swap;
    std::cout << "swapping myclass" << '\n';
    data_.swap(rhs.data_);
  }

private:
  vector<int> data_;
};


struct square {

  square(int n):B(n){}

  int operator()(int x) {
    return x*x;
  }

  myclass B;

  void swap(square& rhs) {
    using std::swap;
    std::cout << "swapping square" << '\n';
    B.swap(rhs.B);
  }
};

void swap(myclass& a, myclass& b) {
  a.swap(b);
}

void swap(square& a, square& b) {
  a.swap(b);
}



using myfunction = std::function<int (int)>;

int main () {
  myfunction myf1(square(10));
  myfunction myf2(square(20));
  myf1.swap(myf2);      /* does not use user-implemented swap functions */

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why would you expect this code to call your own swap? You're swaping `std::function`s, not `myclass`.

Comment: @jrok: I would expect std:function's swap to call the swap function of my functor. I am (obviously) wrong, so is there a way to achieve what I want? In other words, how can I make std::function's swap function call the swap of my functor?

Comment: I don't think you can. `std::function` uses type erasure and there's no way to distinguish two `std::function<int(int)>` objects where one was initialized with `myclass` and the other with a regular function pointer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`std::function::swap(function& other) noexcept` is defined as:

> Effects: interchanges the targets of `*this` and `other`

While this is unclear as to whether it allows the implementation to call `swap` on the targets, it is fairly natural to assume that it does not, since the existence of a `swap` member in the target is erased once the target is put into the `std::function`. This means that it would take significant effort (and runtime inefficiency) for the implementation to know about and call through to the user-defined `swap` in the situations where it existed (while maintaining a backup implementation when the user-defined `swap` was not available).

Furthermore, using the user-defined swap when available, but just swapping pointers in all other situations, would be rather inconsistent and confusing.

In your particular situation, this function is marked `noexcept`, while your `square::swap` implementation is not, and so it would not be legal for any implementation to call it (as it would potentially break the `noexcept` contract).

Comment: the 'noexcept' portion of the answer is absolutely un-true

Comment: why would it be "erased"? and why would it require a run-time support? Template techniques are there for this exact purpose

Comment: @StefanoFalasca: It is erased, since a `std::function<int(int)>` is able to hold both objects that have a `swap` member don't have a `swap` member. Forwarding to the contained `swap` member could only occur when the two `std::function<int(int)>` objects both contain objects of the same type which both have `swap` members. This is not knowable at compile-time (in general), certainly not with templates, without additional runtime information.

Answer (score 2):

From the [documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/swap/) of `std::swap`

> Large data types can provide an overloaded version of this function
>   optimizing its performance. Notably, all standard containers
>   specialize it in such a way that only a few internal pointers are
>   swapped instead of their entire contents, making them operate in
>   constant time.
>
> Many components of the standard library (within std) call swap in an
>   unqualified manner to allow custom overloads for non-fundamental types
>   to be called instead of this generic version: Custom overloads of swap
>   declared in the same namespace as the type for which they are provided
>   get selected through argument-dependent lookup over this generic
>   version.

The [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function/swap2) for the free function `std::swap(std::function)` says:

> Effectively calls lhs.swap(rhs).

while the [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function/swap) for the member function `std::function::swap` doesn't specify anything of the sort.

So, basically, the answer is "there is no guarantee about that", even if from the first quote it seems reasonable that most implementation do call the user defined one by means of using the unqualified call to `swap`.